# Java Increment error() code

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, mouselistener

I have problem incrementing this by one per click.

```
class window extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

int a=0;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint();
    g.drawLine(5, 5, 200, 200); // TEST draw

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    a++; // increment by one
    System.out.println(a);// print out 
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}


class drawSpline_frame extends JFrame {
public drawSpline_frame(){
    setSize(500,500);
    setTitle("Spline");

    Container cp =  this.getContentPane(); // EDITED
    cp.add(window, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            window.addMouseListener(window);
}

}

class drawSpline{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new drawSpline_frame();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't described problem

Comment: You've ignored the answers to your original question by not replying to them, and you're duplicating the same question here. This is not good behavior. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: I'm trying 2 implement mouseListeners in the class Window.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least problems,

1. You've overridden `paint` AND not called `super.paint`
2. You're add a mouse listener each time `paint` is called.  `paint` is called by the paint sub system when ever it decides that the UI needs to be repainted, this means that each the UI is updated, you're adding another mouse listener to the component.

Instead, add the mouse listener once, probably within the constructor. Instead of extending `paint`, you should extend from `paintComponent` and make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    addMouseListener(this);
    g.drawLine(5, 5, 200, 200); // TEST draw

}
```

In your code you are adding listener in `paint(Graphics g)` function !! 
Two things:

1. override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()` and don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method.
2. add Event listener to a component either in constructor or in the block where you are creating it.

Your code `drawSpline_frame()` is incomplete but `content pane's` layout of `JFrame` is by default `BorderLayout()`. you can just do:

```
jFrame.getContentPane().add(windowPan, BorderLayout.Center);
```

As a final suggestion add `MouseListener` event using `MouseAdapter`, you don't need to extend it:

```
  jPanel1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        jPanel1MouseClicked(evt);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Since, I think 1.5, Frame#add delegates to add, so you don't need to use getContentPane. The default position for BorderLayout is CENTER, meaning, you can just call add(windowPan)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Maybe I'm an old fuddy duddy, but I still like using `getContentPane()` since it reminds me where I'm actually adding the component. This has even more importance when trying to change the contentPane's properties such as its background. 1+ to this and your answer.

Comment: yes, but i think it helps me to understand the orientation while adding more than one panel. Just habitual. Anyway, thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: @hovercraft, thanks for the correction. And of, i wanted to say sorry for the other day.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm just lazy, so if don't have to type it ;)

Comment: added mouseAdapter to the paint class, seems 2 work smooth soo far. thanks for response anyway.